# replace anything between a start string and end string (including special char) using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

`update customer  set cust_info= REGEXP_REPLACE(cust_info,'<start><cust_name><start><cust_name><this field has long string><end>','') where user_id=123;`

ORA-12733: regular expression too long

so i tried with `REGEXP_REPLACE(cust_info,'<start>[A-Z0-9_](*.?)<end>','');`
but didn't worked.

I would like to replace anything between `<start>` string and `<end>` string to blank.
(i.e remove anything between`<start>` and `<end>`).

PS:- cust_info column contain long string with html tags.

Comment: It would help if you edited your original post to show the actual data you are working with, and the result you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex seems not to be okay try expression `<start>(.)*?<end>`

```
WITH da AS ( 
SELECT '<start><cust_name><start><cust_name><this field has long string><end>' AS cust_info FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'name_test' AS cust_info FROM dual
) SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(cust_info,'<start>(.)*?<end>','') FROM da;
```

Try

```
UPDATE
    customer
SET
    cust_info = REGEXP_REPLACE(cust_info, '<start>(.)*?<end>', '')
WHERE
    user_id = 123;
```

Explanation:-

```
<start> //Matches literal <start>
    (.) //Matches any character except linebreaks
     *  //Matches 0 or more of the preceding token of (.)
     ?  //Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible
<end>   //Matches literal <end>
```

In case your string has line breaks use the match_parameter to put it into concideration

```
REGEXP_REPLACE ( cust_info, '<start>(.*?)*?<end>' , '' , 1 , 1 , 'n'   )
```

Based on:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE ( source_string, search_pattern
                 [, replacement_string
                    [, star_position
                       [, nth_occurrence
                          [, match_parameter ]
                       ]
                    ]
                 ]
               )
```

Therefore:

```
UPDATE
    customer
SET
    cust_info = REGEXP_REPLACE ( ID_DESC, '<start>(.*?)*?<end>' , '' , 1 , 1 , 'n'   )
WHERE
    user_id = 123;
```

Comment: please explain the (.)*?  as well.

Comment: I think , 1 , 1 , 'n'   ) is not necessary here , since [, star_position                       [, nth_occurrence [, match_parameter ] is default as 1.

Comment: @Roger Yes, true